# Detecting when a Rust move/copy involves actual copy

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization

The [Rust `Copy` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) makes this remark:

> Under the hood, both a copy and a move can result in bits being copied in memory, although this is **sometimes optimized away**.

The documentation provides this code for reference:

```rust
// We can derive a `Copy` implementation. `Clone` is also required, as it's
// a supertrait of `Copy`.
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Foo;

let x = Foo;

let y = x;

// `y` is a copy of `x`

println!("{x:?}"); // A-OK!
```

1. How does one modify this code so that we can detect (and print) at runtime as to whether a variable (`y`) was actually copied in memory or optimized away (by reusing the location of `x`)?
2. Are there any resources to understand the innards of what's happening here?

Comment: As far as I know the only way to know if a copy happens is to examine the produced assembly.

Comment: "`y` is a copy of `x`" is not necessarily true. If you never use `x` again, it might just ignore what you're doing here as `y` is just another name for `x`.

Comment: Note that in your code example, `Foo` is a zero-sized type. Making a copy of a zero-sized type is in some way the same as not making a copy of it.

Comment: For non-zero-sized types, comparing the addresses will show you if the data changed location. But mind that you take the address of `x` before assigning it to `y`, or the fact that you access `&x` may trigger a copy that wouldn't have occurred otherwise.

Comment: Why do you care about whether copies are made? In general, the copies made of `Copy` type instances have very little performance impact. If your concern is performance, I suggest profiling your code (I generally start with [cargo-flamegraph](https://github.com/flamegraph-rs/flamegraph) before trying anything more complex). This will tell you where the bottlenecks are. Most likely, it's not copies of `Copy` types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does one modify this code so that we can detect (and print) at runtime as to whether a variable (y) was actually copied in memory or optimized away (by reusing the location of x)?

You can't. Whether a copy of the memory is optimized away or not is purely up to the compiler, as long as it can prove that the resulting code is equivalent. And because the resulting code is equivalent, 99% of the time you don't need to care.

C++ lets you detect when memory has changed places via copy and move constructors. However, to simplify things, Rust explicitly requires that structures be movable via a simple memory copy, and does not provide a mechanism to specify a custom move implementation.

> Are there any resources to understand the innards of what's happening here?

Beyond looking at how LLVM optimizes code, no.

Comment: For more about looking at compiler output, https://godbolt.org/ has a Rust language option with many rustc versions.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) and Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4) for more about using it effectively.  (Write functions that take args and return something, not starting from constants that will optimize away.)